# Troubles passing string to ajax via javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm getting some issues with a function, where i'm passing 2 arguments, one of them contains a string "12345.00" the main problem is that on console.log(string) this return only "12345".

Is there a way to get the entire string?

```
$data = array(
  array(
    'arg1' => '1', 
    'arg2' => '123'
  ),
  array(
    'arg1' => '2', 
    'arg2' => '12345.00'
  )
);

<button id="openTab">Test</button>

foreach($data as $item){
  <script>                          
    $('#openTab').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      getValues(<?php echo $item['arg1'](); ?>, <?php echo $item['arg2']; ?>);
    });                         
  </script>
}

function getValues(arg1, arg2){
  console.log(arg2);
  new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('getValues') ?>", {
    method: 'POST',
    type: 'json',
    parameters: { arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2},
    onComplete: function(transport) {
      var result = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);         
      console.log(result);     
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? The code you've provided returns the string `"12345.00"` in Chrome.

Comment: Welcome to JS type coercion. But are you sure? I can't reproduce this: `getValues('1', '12345.00'); >  12345.00` Are you manipulating the value in any other way?

Comment: Are you sure, it works for me in Chrome

Comment: That's what happens when you convert the string `12345.00` to a number, so there's code missing from the example.

Comment: I have added my entire script, and on console.log this pass only the string without .00

Comment: The console log of the result of the Ajax call? So this is a server-side conversion issue?

Comment: I don't know exactly, as you say, i have tested on jsfiddle and it works, is strange that in this case it doesnt return the complete string value.

Comment: Unrelated, but this is a radically different question than the original.

Comment: ^. I've added the PHP tag. Your question appears to be "why is PHP's `echo` removing decimal places from my string?"

Comment: I think is the same, the only difference is that first i have added it quoted, so passing a php echo string i missed the quote. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getValues(<?php echo $item['arg1'](); ?>, <?php echo $item['arg2']; ?>);
```

This renders:

```
getValues(2, 12345.00);
```

You need to quote them if you want JS strings:

```
getValues("<?php echo $item['arg1'](); ?>", "<?php echo $item['arg2']; ?>");
```

Which renders:

```
getValues("2", "12345.00");
```

This can be verified by looking at the rendered JS.

You should also code defensively and assume the data that comes back might have quotes in it, e.g., it should be JavaScript-escaped before rendering it into JS.

It's important to understand that your file is basically a template. What happens on the client side is entirely dependent on how it's rendering. You can inspect the rendering by viewing source or inspecting elements to validate what's actually coming across to the browser.

Comment: You're right, quoting the values I've resolved the issue !. Thx a lot